# How to make a function dispatch table with a two dimensional map

Tags: c++

I want to make a function dispatch table with a 2 dimensional map but i can't figure out how to make a brace enclosed list.

```
enum state_t{
OPENED,
CLOSED,
OPENING,
CLOSING,
}

state_t do_something(instance_data *data);
state_t do_bar(instance_data *data);
std::map<const state_t, std::map<const state_t, std::function<state_t(instance_data *data)>>> state_table
{
 {{OPENED, OPENED}, do_something},
 {{OPENED, CLOSING}, do_bar}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem misunderstood smth. The proper initializer list for map in map should look like bellow. `const` for the key type argument is odd, the key type is const inside the map.

```
std::map<state_t, std::map<state_t, std::function<state_t(instance_data *data)>>> state_table
{{ OPENED, {
    {OPENED, do_something},
    {CLOSING}, do_bar}
 }}
};
```

However you might want to use `std::pair` or `std::tuple`

```
std::map<std::pair<state_t, state_t>, std::function<state_t(instance_data *data)>> state_table
{
  {{ OPENED, OPENED }, do_something},
  {{ OPENED, CLOSING}, do_bar}
};
```